# Redefine jQuery using document.writeln()

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a Javascript library which is currently in use by our websites (> 8000).
Websites are calling a bootstrapper js that on it's turn will reference some other library scripts.

Since our JavaScript library heavily uses jQuery, it's currently included in the bootstrapper as well.

This is done using document.writeln:

```
document.writeln("<script src=\"js\/jquery-1.4.4.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>");
```

I'm aware that document.writeln isn't xHtml compliant and there are much better solutions, but this is just the way it currently works fine for all our websites and getting rid of document.writeln is not an option.

The problem now is that we get conflicts when a site already defines a lower version of jQuery. So, we decided redefine jQuery in our library:

```
document.writeln("<script src=\"js\/jquery-1.4.4.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>");
document.writeln("<script type=\"text\/javascript\">");    
document.writeln("   var $myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();");
document.writeln("</script>");
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jQuery.noConflict()` only frees the `$()` and not `jQuery()` and maybe that's the problem. You could try doing it manually (but see below for a better way) like this:

```
<script>
  theOld$ = $;
  theOldjQuery = jQuery;
</script>
<script src=jquery-new-version.js></script>
<script>
  $ = theOld$;
  newjQuery = jQuery;
  jQuery = theOldjQuery;
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** A better way to do the same (thanks to T.J. Crowder for the tip) would be:

```
<script src=jquery-new-version.js></script>
<script>
  newjQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

See the docs for [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: +1, v. good point. You should add that `noConflict(true)` will release both of them.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks, I didn't know that noConflict(true) releases both of them. I'll update my example.

Comment: Re your edit, you don't need to do all that, `noConflict` handles it. Literally all he needs to do is `var myJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);`. That will restore the old values of `$` and `jQuery`. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/icowo5

Answer (score 2):

As quoted, it's probably not working because of this line:

```
document.writeln("</script>");
```

You need to break up that `</script>` tag in the string to prevent the browser from seeing it and thinking the script ends there. E.g.:

```
document.writeln("<\/script>");
```

You've done this with the earlier ones in your quoted code, but not the new one.

See also [rsp's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325303/redefine-jquery-using-document-writeln/5325352#5325352), you may need the `true` argument to `noConflict` in order to release the `jQuery` symbol, not just the `$` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

you may find usefull the way jquery is included at html5boilerplate.com:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

so you may perform checks of jQuery object presence on page and also jQuery version

```
// Returns string Ex: "1.5.1"
$().jquery;
```